# Nessus web client: Error 401 invalid credentials

Tags: network-scanners

Previously I used to scan sites using Nessus web client, but when I tried to login with the same credentials I am able to see a401 (Invalid Credentials) error. I have restarted the service nessusd, still facing the same issue.

It would be helpful if anyone suggests me a solution.

Comment: This is a question for Nessus support.

Answer (score 0):

First check you are entering the username which exists(presuming you're using linux)

`ls /opt/nessus/var/nessus/users/`

if user exists, reset the password and try again with new password.

In the command-line, type:

- On Windows :
  `C:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus\nessus-chpasswd.exe <username>`
- On Linux:
  `sudo /opt/nessus/sbin/nessus-chpasswd <username>`
- On Mac:
  `sudo /Library/Nessus/run/sbin/nessus-chpasswd`

Note: Root/Admin Privileges required.

**EDITED JUNE 7, 2020**

This is no longer accurate. Per [tenable.com](https://docs.tenable.com/nessus/commandlinereference/Content/ChangeAUsersPassword.htm)...

- On Windows:
  `c:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus\nessuscli.exe chpasswd <username>`
- On Linux:
  `/opt/nessus/sbin/nessuscli chpasswd <username>`
- No instructions are given for Mac, but assuming the same approach: 
  `/Library/Nessus/run/sbin/nessuscli chpasswd <username>`